# Not able to GET with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm not able to `UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com")` for some reason. It just returns an empty object `{}`.

Comment: I thought that from your question, you might have tried `console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com")`. If my understanding is correct, in that case, HTTPResponse is returned. I think that this might be the reason of your issue. In your situation, please use the method of `getContentText()` like `console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com").getContentText()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `.getContentText()`

E.g. `UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com").getContentText()`